# position controls on browser screen using asp.net

Tags: asp.net, controls, position

i want to position elements on certain locations on the screen (asp:button, asp:label...)

is using asp:table and asp:tableCell and asp:tableRow are the best way? 
i used that in ASP.NET 2.0, are there are newer ways to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I like to use just regular markup, like `div`, `table`, etc. With CSS and regular HTML elements, you should be able to get a pixel perfect layout with a little bit of effort.